# GWT Refresh Compile Cycle

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, servlets

According to what I have read concerning gwt, whenever we change the java code and reload the browser, the change is reflected. This is true for client side but not true for localhost serverside.

Does somebody know how to refresh the server side as well on browser refresh for gwt or is it not possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hot deploy with Eclipse, Netbeans, IDEA etc. But for this usage you must use debug mode. In addition, IDE loses its state because of many changes so debug mode must be restarted.

I think there is no way to refresh changes and I think keyword is hot deploy

Answer (score 2):

If you're executing your GWT webapp from Eclipse. You only need to go to the "Development Mode" tab and use the "Reload Web Server" option.

Answer (score 0):

If your run GWT in Development mode within Eclipse, with a Spring backend Eclipse is usually clever enough to hot deploy server-side class changes, but not all of them.